# Telegram bot long polling stops at 50s

Tags: telegram, long-polling

I wrote a simple C++ program where I use libcurl to send a HTTP POST request at getUpdates URL with the parameter timeout=3600 but it returns after 50 seconds instead of the 1 hour required.

Does anybody know how to set the Telegram long polling time longer than 50 seconds?

Thanks,
Simone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with your code, I found the same problem with my python implementation. 50sec seems to be the maximum.